# what is the proper way to backup outlook 2010 settings and cache?

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, cache, office365

We're planning to reinstall some workstations which use outlook 2010 and office365.
What do i need to backup/restore in order to avoid the re-creation of the .ost (cache file) ?

Comment: You backup the folder that contains the .ost file.

Comment: The very first Google search I did resulted in http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010354943.aspx and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_storage/does-office-365-outlook-keep-its-outlook-data/ba3ed372-ac5d-4a48-875b-c14d3b68cd99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are exerpts from [community.office365.com](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/238416.aspx)

> there isn’t any option to copy and restore the OST file to another
>   workstation
>
> he OST file have a serial, that is tied to each profile, and when even
>   you créate a new profile, this have to re-download the entire content
>   again

So to reduce the bandwith utilisation I will ask users to move their old mails to a subfolder and then exclude this folder from synchronization ...